# My node js server is not starting is my code wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, localhost

```
var http = require('http')

var courses = [{id : 1, name : 'JS'},{id : 2 , name : 'node'}]
var users =['userA','userB']

var server = http.createServer(function (request,response){

    console.log('got request!', request);

    if(request.url === '/api/courses') {
        response.write(JSON.stringify(courses));
        response.end
    }
    else if(request.url === '/api/users'){
        response.write(JSON.stringify(users));
        response.end
    }
    else{
        response.write('hello world :)');
        response.end
    }
})


server.listen(30232)
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages when using 'node yourfile.js'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare two `var` you have to do in separate lines or use `;`. This code should work to you:

```
var http = require('http')

var courses = [{id : 1, name : 'JS'},{id : 2 , name : 'node'}]
var users =['userA','userB']

var server = http.createServer(function (request,response){

console.log('got request!', request);

if(request.url === '/api/courses') {
    response.write(JSON.stringify(courses));
    response.end
}
else if(request.url === '/api/users'){
    response.write(JSON.stringify(users));
    response.end
}
else{
    response.write('hello world :)');
    response.end
}

})

server.listen(30232)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is quite simple.

```
var http = require("http");

var courses = [
  { id: 1, name: "JS" },
  { id: 2, name: "node" },
];
var users = ["userA", "userB"];

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  console.log("got request!", request);

  if (request.url === "/api/courses") {
    response.write(JSON.stringify(courses));
    response.end();
  } else if (request.url === "/api/users") {
    response.write(JSON.stringify(users));
    response.end();
  } else {
    response.write("hello world :)");
    response.end();
  }
});

server.listen(30232);
```

First, the two variables at the top are declared incorrectly, you must separate them with a semicolon and secondly, when handling requests, the `response.end()` is a function and you haven't used it as a function, so there's the issue. Add parentheses for `response.end()` and it must work correctly.

Comment: Thanks sir but still not rendering in my browser it returns the object but not renders in browser

Comment: Can you tell what exactly is happening or maybe upload an image? Because when I ran it in my browser, the home page was working correctly.